# How can I save a PHP backtrace to the error log?

Tags: php, error-handling, backtrace

I'm using this right now:

```
error_log(serialize(debug_backtrace()));
```

But I have to unserialize it every time. Is there a better way to store backtraces?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This should generate a readable string:

```
error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
```

Additionally, [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_print_backtrace) prints the back trace as string and its output can be captured with regular output buffer functions:

```
ob_start();
debug_print_backtrace();
error_log(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: `debug_backtrace()` returns a big array, which doesn't print_r real well.  The second method prints a nicer looking backtrace.  Another method I sometimes use is just `error_log(new Exception('message here, if you want'));` because I like the way the backtrace is formatted for exceptions.

Comment: @JayK - FWIW, sassman on a comment on Igor's answer says about Exception: *"But it does not include the variables of the calling scope. The benefit of debug_print_backtrace() is it includes a copy of the runtime context."*

Answer (score 28):

From my perspective the best approach is using an exception functionality:

```
$e = new Exception();
$e->getTraceAsString();
```

Comment: it prints the trace, yes. But it does not include the variables of the calling scope. The benefit of debug_print_backtrace() is it includes a copy of the runtime context.

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `(new \Exception())->getTraceAsString()`

Comment: And in PHP 7+, slightly shorter: `(new \Error)->getTraceAsString()`

Answer (score 8):

```
    $log = var_export(debug_backtrace(), true);
```

Then use the variable `$log` to log in file or what ever.

Comment: var_export does not handle circular references. Therefore that solution is not safe to use.

Answer (score 5):

For those who might want a more compact version, this will also do the trick:

```
error_log((new Exception())->getTraceAsString())
```

Answer (score 4):

A little ugly but workable, I do this:

```
 error_log('Identifying string so that it doesn\'t just end up as gibberish' . json_encode(debug_backtrace()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can either be written to a .txt file or you can also access it's contents (like $content[0]) as opposed to var_export which is a bit trickier I find:

```
    $content = unserialize(serialize(debug_backtrace()));
```